# Plotly: Multiple plots with 'linked' interactivity

Tags: plotly

I am trying to create a series of plots to embed in a website where the interactivity is 'linked' like in the animation below. I cannot find examples of this functionality in Plotly (or other embeddable plotting packages).

The first two plots just show a synchronized vertical bar, the bottom plot shows the corresponding values of plot 1 in a scatterplot.

[image]

**Questions:** Is it possible to create this type of 'linked' plots using Plotly? If so, can anyone point me in a direction on how to accomplish that? If not, are there other plotting packages that offer this plotting functionality?

*(P.S. I used Wolfram Mathematica and random data to create the animation)*

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can achieve this using [plotly's Embed API](https://github.com/plotly/Embed-API), which allows you to handle events such as click or mouseover above any plotly graphs embedded in a iframe.

For something similar to the above animation, I recommend taking a look at [this example](http://chriddyp.github.io/interactive-heatmaps/). You can find the associated [repo here](https://github.com/chriddyp/interactive-heatmaps).

Comment: Thanks etpinard, I think that is what I was looking for. I am not that familiar with javascript yet, but the example helps a lot.