# Can I interactively highlight a datapoint in multiple Python Plotly plots?

Tags: python, plotly

I've got a couple (or more) plotly subplots with scatter points in an offline Jupyter notebook:

```
fig = py.tools.make_subplots(rows=2, cols=1)

trace = go.Scatter(mode='markers', x=x, y=y, text=uid)
fig.append_trace(trace)

trace2 = go.Scatter(mode='markers', x=x2, y=y2, text=uid)
fig.append_trace(trace2)

iplot(fig)
```

[image]

When I hover over a datapoint, I see a unique ID for the point (as specified above by `text=uid`) - "subject_025" in this screenshot.

With the point highlighted in the top subplot, I'm curious to find the corresponding point in the bottom subplot.

Is there a way in Python plotly to bind the hover action across different plots, such that a single datapoint can be highlighted in multiple places?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Plotly: Multiple plots with 'linked' interactivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30214660/plotly-multiple-plots-with-linked-interactivity)

Comment: @FlorianBrucker that answer seems to be javascript-specific. Is it possible with Python?

Comment: Did you have a look at Plotly's Dash?

Comment: Dash Python API does not seem to handle this case. [Here](https://community.plotly.com/t/programmatically-trigger-hover-events-with-dash/42443) is the nearest solution I've found.