# Is there a plotly function for interaction between different graphs like the R highlight_key() but in Python?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

Using Plotly in R it is possible to generate interaction between different graphs easily with the help of the `highlight_key()` function, as can be seen in the link and in the example below:

https://plotly-r.com/client-side-linking

```
require(plotly)

# load the `txhousing` dataset
data(txhousing, package = "ggplot2")

# declare `city` as the SQL 'query by' column
tx <- highlight_key(txhousing, ~city)

# initiate a plotly object
base <- plot_ly(tx, color = I("black")) %>% 
  group_by(city)

# create a time series of median house price
time_series <- base %>%
  group_by(city) %>%
  add_lines(x = ~date, y = ~median)

# remember, `base` is a plotly object, but we can use dplyr verbs to
# manipulate the input data 
# (`txhousing` with `city` as a grouping and querying variable)
dot_plot <- base %>%
  summarise(miss = sum(is.na(median))) %>%
  filter(miss > 0) %>%
  add_markers(
    x = ~miss, 
    y = ~forcats::fct_reorder(city, miss), 
    hoverinfo = "x+y"
  ) %>%
  layout(
    xaxis = list(title = "Number of months missing"),
    yaxis = list(title = "")
  ) 

subplot(dot_plot, time_series, widths = c(.2, .8), titleX = TRUE) %>%
  layout(showlegend = FALSE) %>%
  highlight(on = "plotly_selected", dynamic = TRUE, selectize = TRUE)
```

With highlight_key() it is possible to create a "new" dataframe which Plotly will use to automatically generate interactivity. Is there something similar for Python?

I saw this old post, but perhaps there is something more optimized and simple nowadays.

[Plotly: Multiple plots with 'linked' interactivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30214660/plotly-multiple-plots-with-linked-interactivity)

Comment: No, there is no such function in python. But you can pass a [`post_script`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bplotly%5D+post_script) to the `.show()` method, that is, a javascript snippet that runs in the browser when the plot renders, in this context you can directly use the Plotly.js API to handle interactions (@see [functions](https://plotly.com/javascript/plotlyjs-function-reference) and [events](https://plotly.com/javascript/plotlyjs-events/), you definitely don't need the old postMessage api from the link).